# PyTorch: Build from source with TBB failed

Tags: python, build, pytorch, openmp, tbb

I am trying to build PyTorch from source using TBB instead of OpenMP but I am getting the following errors every time:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier'
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `omp_in_parallel'
    /usr/bin/ld: <PATH>/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/kernel_function_legacy_test.dir/build.make:109: bin/kernel_function_legacy_test] Error 1
```

You can find the full log file [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YXSicCUcDm2jZyY8n0al8EdJ9TbychWO/view?usp=sharing):

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. `git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch`
2. `cd pytorch`
3. `ATEN_THREADING=TBB BUILD_BINARY=1 USE_EIGEN_THREADPOOL=1 USE_CUDA=0 PARALLEL_BACKEND=NATIVE_TBB USE_OPENMP=0 USE_TBB=1 MKL_THREADING=TBB BLAS=MKL USE_MKLDNN=1 MKLDNN_THREADING=TBB BUILD_BINARY=1 python setup.py build --cmake 2>&1 | tee ~/output.txt`

- PyTorch Version (e.g., 1.0): 1.10.0a0+git1798ff0
- OS (e.g., Linux): Manjaro
- How you installed PyTorch (`conda`, `pip`, source): pip
- Python version: 3.9.5
- CUDA/cuDNN version: NO
- GPU models and configuration: NO

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is issue with Caffe2 CMake files.
Have you tried  updating CMake to latest version.

A similar  issue could be found on  github. Where the issue was resolved by upgrading cmake.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8370